# MacBook Pro detects syncmaster (monitor) but doesn't display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

My new MacBook Pro 13" touch bar is connected to my Samsung Syncmaster monitor through USB-c hub -> HDMI -> DVI. It detects the screen (shows up on OSX) but nothing is displayed on my screen. I have connected the MacBook on my LG TV through USB-c hub -> HDMI and everything works.

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely because you are doing two conversions of the video signal and at some point it's either being  degraded and/or becoming out of sync.

The *two* conversions I am referring to is going from DisplayPort to HDMI then going from HDMI to DVI.  In your original question, you never mention specifically what adapters you are using nor if they are active or passive.

Why an "active" adapter? [Active adapters "recreates" the signal and passive just reorders the signals.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271)

To solve this issue, you need to limit your adapter to just one conversion (no conversions at all is ideal - mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort) and do so with an [*active* DisplayPort to DVI adapter](http://radnex.us/usbc-mdp-dvi-vga-hdmi-adapter).

Comment: I can't test anymore as I had to buy a new screen and sold the syncmaster...

Comment: No worries - in the future just keep in mind that the less you have to convert, the more reliable it will be.  Just a rule of thumb.