# Macbook Pro not detecting Dell monitor - Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina, usb, hdmi

I am trying to connect a 15-inch Macbook Pro 2017 to a p3418HW Dell monitor, through a USB-C to HDMI adapter ([VTIN 4Kx2K USB-C to HDMI](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B013OZD3WY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)). The monitor shows: "No HDMI signal from your device".

I have tried the following suggestions on the net, with **NO result**:

- resetting SMC
- resetting NVRAM
- several times disconnecting and reconnecting power and HDMI cables with different orders

I have also tried the cable, adapter with the same monitor with a **13-inch Macbook Pro 2016** and strangely everything works well!!

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the manufacturer and model of the USB-C-to-HDMI adapter?

Comment: Bought it long ago, it's a non-Apple brand: [VTIN](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B013OZD3WY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: Thank you, it may help someone troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: The dupe references a 4K display while this one HD.  The issue is the same, however - you should get an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391724/119271) as it produces a *true* HDMI signal.  Your monitor, however, has DisplayPort inputs.  I would get a [USB-C to DisplayPort](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282019/119271) cable instead - it's less expensive (no adapter necessary) and more reliable (no converting of signals)