# macOS 13 ventura would not detect external monitor

Tags: macos, display

After I upgrade to macOS 13 ventura, mac no longer detect my external monitor samsung G9 neo. no matter what I do, pull out display wire, restart Mac, the issue remains.

Comment: Unless you’re going from DisplayPort to DisplayPort, you should be using an [Active Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295073/119271) and not a passive cable.  This is a common issue with Macs not syncing the clock signal properly and an active adapter solves this issue every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all kinds of try, I am not sure it is samsung G9 NEO issue or it is macOS 13 ventura issue.
I don't know who should be blamed. However, I find a simple fix.

Step 1: turn off external monitor

Step 2: restart MacOS 13 ventura

Step 3: turn on external monitor

vola,

If you don't power off exernal monitor at the first place, the issue will never go away, no matter if you unplug display port wire, restart Mac, issue will remains.

The key is power off external monitor, which "unregister" it with Mac,
then you restart Mac, let mac "reset" display device list.
Now you turn on external monitor, let mac "register" a new external display device.

Comment: Great! As you mentioned, key is the detail of turning it off!! I was already about to downgrade, you saved me a lot of effort!

Comment: Okay what the heck... this is the only thing that worked for me. Expected it to be a folly attempt.

Comment: Apple does not fix this bug even on MacOS 13.0.1 ventura.  Still tlhe same bug. No worry, as long as you know the trick to power off external monitor at the first place.

Comment: As said elsewhere, check this out:

That may work for Samsung televisions, but not with Panasonic ones.

The problem arose with macOS 13 Ventura. No problem before. No problem with Apple silicon Macs.

The problem arises with Intel Macs only, like the iMac, when connecting its Thunderbolt port using "Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter" to HDMI cable to HDMI port of TV. The TV is not detected by the Mac.

I have not tried Intel Macs with HDMI port, like Mac mini.               macOS 13 Ventura BREAKS Panasonic TV connection via HDMI https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254775822