# High Sierra display issues with external monitor

Tags: display, high-sierra

Whenever I boot the machine, or wake it from sleep, with an external monitor connected, the laptop screen flicker and dim/undim for at least a whole minute (while the external display remains black) before finally turning on. While this is going on the machine is also very slow, and responds poorly to keyboard/trackpad input. This does not happen if I do not have an external monitor connected.

**Specifications:**

- High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88)
- Macbook Pro (15", 2017)
- External monitor is connected through an [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) (HDMI)
- The machine is connected to a power cable

**What I've tried**

I've tried resetting NVRAM and SMC to no avail.

Comment: ***We're missing a lot of details here***.  How is this monitor connected?  Which MacBook?  Which build of High Sierra?  Are you connected to power or on battery?  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: @Allan See updated question.

Comment: My first thoughts are the "official" Apple AV adapter is flaky at best and that it would be beneficial to go DisplayPort to DisplayPort rather than HDMI.  But if you *must* go HDMI, use an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282019/119271).  What monitor are you using and does it support DisplayPort?