# 15" MacBook Pro 2016 External Monitors cause screen flickering

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, screen, hdmi

I've had my Macbook for a while, and since I now have gotten a new desk and monitors, I've hooked them up for a dual external display setup. I've linked the products I use below.

- [HDMI Cords x2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FX6ST8G)
- [HP Pavilion 21.5-Inch IPS LED HDMI VGAMonitors x2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015WCV70W)
- [Redragon M601 Gaming Mouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HTK1NCS)
- [2 Official Adapters](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter)

When I wake my Mac from sleep, often times the first monitor turns on, and begins flickering, dimming the display and then going black, and repeating the cycle. Again with the MacBook display. The third monitor often just doesn't turn on, which I imagine is causing the infinite loop.

I've contacted Apple support numerous times and setup Genius Bar Appointments. I've reset the NVRAM and all of the things you can reset on boot. Anyone know whats going on or why this is happening? Preferably how to fix it.

Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Is it only from sleep or does it do it from a hard boot/reboot?   Also, you should be using an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282019/119271)  and not passive "cords"

Comment: @Allan I haven't noticed it from a reboot. Usually just on wake from sleep. Passive cords meaning normal adapter and HDMI cables?

Comment: It's not "normal" or "abnormal" it just "is."  DisplayPort (what's coming out of your MBP) and HDMI (what you are converting to) are two *very* different signals.  In fact, the clock sync voltage is quite different.  A passive adapter "reorganizes" the signals from DP to HDMI where an active adapter actually *recreates* the signal.  See [Active vs. Passive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275532/macbook-air-occasionally-freezes-when-external-monitor-is-connected/275978#275978).