# Macbook PRO 2015 doesn't recognize my external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I bought a new monitor, a [ViewSonic VA2259-sh](https://www.viewsonic.com/ph/products/lcd/VA2259-sh.php) and it's not getting recognized by my MBP 2015.

I tried the monitor in my desktop and a rpi, and it gets recognized. In my MBP 2015, the monitor shows “No Signal” every time I plug in/out the hdmi.

My old external monitor works perfectly with my Mac though.

Already tried [this steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201177) with no luck.

macOS Catalina v10.15.5

Comment: What was the desktop that worked? (What's an RPI?) Is the monitor recognised in System Preferences or About This Mac (even when NO Signal)? I'd be tempted to try another cable, even that one worked for the other monitor/computer.

Comment: @benwiggy The desktop that worked has a RX 560 in it with the same cable used. RPI is a Raspberry Pi, same cable used and it worked.

Comment: Did you try power cycling the monitor?  Also, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282019/119271) from a similar question

Comment: I did @Allan. I'll try again though.

Comment: Just to make sure...power cycling while connected to your MBP

Comment: Noted @Allan thanks. WIll give feedback.

Comment: What sort of cable are you using? Have you tried more than one method?

Comment: HDMI @TonyWilliams. Also tried it with a thunderbolt to hdmi. Nothing worked.

Comment: nAre you sure about the dongle you're using? That's often the problem. I assume that you are connecting to the Raspberry Pi over HDMI and are using the same cable when testing the MacBook.

Comment: Yes I am using the same cable with my RPi and Mac @TonyWilliams

Comment: How long is your HDMI cable? I've seen situation where a display worked fine on non-Mac, but would not work on a MacBook. Most cases the cable was too long, which resulted in the Mac not accepting the signal.