# HDMI display will sometimes not wake on but SSH works

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini, monterey, power-management

Ever since upgrading my Macmini8,1 to OS v12 or 12.3, the display will sometimes not wake the next morning when I try to use it. When in this state, nothing I try gets me a working display and I am forced to power cycle. ((This is especially frustrating because of all the publicity about this issue supposedly being "Mac M1 only".))

What I tried:

- Power cycling display
- SSH into mac mini, proving it is awake...
- Switching HDMI1 and HDMI2 cables on the monitor, serving as an "unplug video" and proving my Raspberry Pi can display on either HDMI port.
- In System Prefs I disabled ALL power management
- ...because Power Management is off everywhere, at night before bed I must power off the display.
- I've firmly pressed power button (1 second), waited a few seconds, then pushed it again (1 second)
- Yesterday I tried booting into Recovery, and did a full network **OS reinstall**. Problem happened again this morning...

In the morning, it is 50-50 chance whether display wakes. (I have not tried not leaving the monitor on overnight... it gives off too much light even when the display is blacked)

While problem is happening, Terminal says:

```
$ pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 womp                 1
 autorestart          1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 proximitywake        1
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                0
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         0
 tcpkeepalive         1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 standbydelaylow      86400
```

```
$ sysctl -n hw.model
Macmini8,1
```

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.3.1
BuildVersion:   21E258
```

Monitor is an LG 27BK85U and it has all sleep and low-power settings disabled. It will turn off if it does not get a signal, but swapping HDMI cables can serve to nudge it awake (a brighter black), but the LG thinks it does not have a signal from the Mac so it goes full dark in a few seconds.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Belated update... (thanks for the ping @Upendra): This never fixed itself with HDMI. Tried everything. I was able to switch from HDMI to a Display Port cable; DP did not have the problem. It's a software issue for sure (as it used to work) but DP switch is what worked for me..

Comment: See this [question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/281590/119271).  The Mac uses a DisplayPort signal; HDMI is different especially the absence of a  clock signal.  The issue is the Apple kexts (drivers) are not forgiving enough when it comes to “re-syncing” the signals.

Comment: Also see this post: [What’s wrong with HDMI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271).  IMO, DisplayPort is the better signal for computing.  HDMI works better for consumer electronics.