# MacBook Pro M3 detects monitor but got black screen

Tags: display, dock, hdmi, apple-silicon

I am trying to connect my home screen via HDMI using a dock. It shows the monitor in the Displays tab in settings but I keep having a black screen on the external monitor.
I also have a Dell laptop and it works fine on it, both through the dock and directly plugged on my Dell.

I tried many things. Changing the resolution of the mac, restarting it, unplugging all cables except for the HDMI. Switching the USB-C ports that my dock is connected through etc.

It also works fine at my workplace (which I can connect directly on the mac). I don't know what else I can try.

My monitor is a AOC Q27G2G4 that I bought 2-3 years ago.

Comment: Can you connect directly from the Mac to the monitor (no dock)?

Comment: No @Allan, my monitor uses HDMI and my Mac has USB-C ports only.

Comment: [USB-C to HDMI active adapters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282019/119271) are not overly expensive;  we need to eliminate the dock from the equation so to narrow down the cause of the problem

Comment: What brand/model of USBC dock are you using? It may well be incompatible. I've tested several USBC docks/hubs over the past few years for our classrooms, and they are not all created equal, even the one's marked macOS Compatible.