# How to play a movie on a MacBook using a multimedia projector for output?

Tags: audio, video, appletv, airplay, streaming

At our school there are (not smart) BenQ multimedia projectors in every classrom, every one of these is connected to an AppleTV (AppleTVs are *not* connected to WiFi) via HDMI cable and more and more colleagues are telling me that there seems to be no way to play a video stream (or a movie from the media library they own) containing image and sound via AirPlay or even via HDMI (using the official Apple adapter) now: the sound is perfectly fine, but there is only black rectangle instead of video even if the MacBook is connected directly to the beamer via HDMI.

So my question is: is there a way to stream a movie without using a Windows laptop?

YouTube (not YouTube Movies!) works perfectly fine btw.

Are our (quite) old projectors causing the problem?

**Update:** Looks like it's a DRM problem. VGA connection (via Apple adapter) works perfectly fine: the movie and its soundtrack are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a DRM problem and the only way to "solve" it is using a VGA adapter. Still waiting for a "stripper" to be delivered.

Answer (score 1):

A projector is nothing more than a monitor that projects an image using a lamp and lens rather than an LED panel.  Treat it as such for simplicity.

> every one of these is connected to an AppleTV (AppleTVs are not connected to WiFi)….there seems to be no way to play a video stream … via AirPlay or even via HDMI….

#### [AirPlay requires WiFi](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289)

If you’re not using the same WiFi for both the Mac/iPhone/iPad, AirPlay won’t work.

#### Use an Active HDMI adapter.

The “official” Apple adapter is a passive one, meaning it just reorders the DisplayPort (DP or mDP) signal into HDMI.  You need an adapter that actually *recreates* the signal,  I wrote on this topic: [What’s Wrong with HDMI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271) previously.  Whether you have an older MacBook with a mini DisplayPort (mDP) or Thunderbolt 1 or 2 port, or if you have a newer Mac with Type-C ports, [when converting to HDMI, always use an Active Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283446/119271)

**Update:** Looks like it's a DRM problem. VGA connection (via Apple adapter) works perfectly fine: the movie and its soundtrack are there.

Comment: I do, but any monitor connected to our MacBooks works just fine. AppleTV is able to create its own WiFi hotspot, but still needs a WiFi connection for streaming? It might explain why screen sharing (like GoodNotes via AirPlay) works perfectly fine, but movies don't.

Comment: Looks like it's a DRM problem. VGA connection (via Apple adapter) works perfectly fine: the movie and its soundtrack are there.

Comment: That makes sense. Glad to see you got it sorted

Comment: @georgmierau It would be great to write your finding up into a brief answer and mark it as accepted!