# Logical HDMI display reconnection

Tags: terminal, hdmi, driver, kernel-extensions

I have a Mac mini server with Yosemite, and I plugged a VGA Display using a VGA/HDMI adapter.

The issue is, when I shut down or restart the server, the display is not recognized, then I need to go to unplug and plug again, and server now recognizes the display.

I need to know how to make a logical "reconnection" for the adapter.

For example on Windows I use a [devcom](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) application to enable or disable the devices.

I was reading that the possible solution is using a `kextunload` command on terminal.

I don't know which kextfile I need to "unload" for the HDMI adapter.

On terminal:

`/System/Library/Extensions/`

`kextunload exampleflile.kext`

`kextload examplefile.kext`

Anybody have an idea about my issue? Another way to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Greetings from Mexico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need an **active** [HDMI to VGA adapter](http://radnex.us/HDMI-to-VGA-Active-Adapter).  There is a bunch of signaling conversion that goes on with an adapter, especially when it goes from digital (HDMI) to analog (VGA).  An active adapter will reformat the signals so it's a true VGA signal rather than just supply the correct pin outs.

Take a look at this answer, [Passive vs. Active adapters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) - I talk about the difference and why it's important.