# External display connected via USB-C > VGA goes to endless sleep/wake loop

Tags: macos, mojave, vga

I have a dell external display connected to my mb pro 2017 (Mojave), but whenever i try to sleep my mac (with sleep command), it goes to endless loop trying to sleep and then immediately wakes up, because external display won't sleep.

Is there any workarounds / apps to prevent this behavior?

Comment: How do you know it is the display ? does it sleep if your turn it off ?

Comment: if i turn off the monitor, mac still thinks as it's on and won't sleep, strange behavior.

Comment: So it does go to sleep but immediately wakes back up?

Comment: Yes, i've noticed if i use sleep on external display's menu, then both macbook and external display would go to sleep as intended, but if i use sleep on a macbook itself, then external display won't sleep.

Comment: It's probably the USB-C(DisplayPort) to VGA adapter.  Try using an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283979/119271) so that it recreates the actual VGA signals.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to put the mac in to sleep using external display. Also closing the LID won't work, you have to sleep the external display first, then you can close the LID.

Answer (score 0):

First run the `pmset -g` in Terminal

PMset is the Power Management settings.

to see your settings.

Then reset those settings to Defaults with

```
pmset -c 2 -b 1 -u 1; pmset -g
```

To find out who is actually keeping it from Sleep use `pmset -g assertions`

The report in Terminal looks like this example (without Sleep problems)

[image]

From this (yours) report we should see what is preventing the Mac from Sleeping.

Comment: That's not the issue. I know about `pmset`, thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderKim I was trying to help and you did not disclose that in your post.