# macOS Catalina 10.15.4 - MacBook Pro Retina, mid 2015 - dual screen bug

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina, hdmi, dual-screen

Since updating to Catalina two months ago I have had this problem: My MacBook Pro HDMI output is attached to a NEC monitor. Every time I log in on my standard account the monitors are mirrored and Catalina only recognizes the MBP screen. There is no way to turn off mirroring or select the second screen-it doesn't show in system preferences, which only detects the MBP retina screen.

```
****About this Mac****
  Chipset Model:    Intel Iris Pro
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  1536 MB
  Vendor:   Intel
  Device ID:    0x0d26
  Revision ID:  0x0008
  Metal:    Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily1 v4
  Displays:
Color LCD:
  Display Type: Built-In Retina LCD
  Resolution:   2880 x 1800 Retina
  Framebuffer Depth:    24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  No
  Connection Type:  Internal
**P221W:NEC Monitor ---**
  Resolution:   1680 x 1050 (Widescreen Super eXtended Graphics Array Plus)
  UI Looks like:    1680 x 1050 @ 60 Hz
  Framebuffer Depth:    24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Display Serial Number:    07104621NA  
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  No
```

**The problem didn't exist before the Catalina upgrade.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t recommend HDMI for any sort of compute type of environment.  It’s a *consumer* electronics video technology and very flaky (IMO).    My recommendation for connecting your monitor to your MacBook is as follows:

- [DisplayPort to DVI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295073/119271) (Active Adapter)
- [HDMI to DVI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283979/119271) (Active Adapter)

The reason I recommend active adapters is because DVI and even the analog VGA signals have very different signaling from HDMI.  Most of the time, the issue is a missing clock sync.  The passive adapters can’t recreate this signal where the active ones can.

Many times, you’ll see the same setup in Windows (even on Bootcamp!) work without a problem.  Windows drivers have a wider “tolerance” for these idiosyncrasies where as Apple doesn’t.  The active adapters fix that problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will go ahead and purchase a DisplayPort to DVI cable. Hope this makes for a better viewing experience for the NEC screen!

Answer (score 0):

Besides trying the normal stuff like [Resetting NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), you might want to double check your Energy Saver settings and make sure "[Automatic graphics switching](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202043)" is enabled.

If you still have trouble, check under the About This Mac--> System Report--> Graphics/Displays. Then take a picture of that and send it over. I'm curious if your MacBook Pro is having trouble with the AMD Radeon card or the drivers that support it.

Comment: Greetings and thank you for the suggestions. I may need to try Resetting tips. My MBPro has an integral graphics card (Intel Iris Pro) rather than an AMD Radeon card. One thing that worked: unplug the HDMI to DVI from the MBPro and plugging it back in and then the second NEC screen was recognized and mirroring went away!

Comment: Great news! The HDMI can be a little temperamental as there's a whole discussion that happens between the chipset, the cable, and the device connected -- so that may be your go-to solution for a bit.