# Mac mini incompatibility with HDMI to VGA

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport, vga-adapter

I was reading about what is happening to me now with a Mac mini and many people report it, what I understood is that from HDMI to VGA, it does not send a signal since it is analog and it does not work.

My question is could I go from HDMI to DVI, then from DVI to VGA; would it work?

[Guiding question](https://superuser.com/questions/330393/apple-mac-mini-wont-work-with-hdmi-to-vga-converter)

It should be noted that my first port which is the mini DisplayPort I am already occupying it; this would be for my second screen.

Comment: Have an HDMI to VGA adapter that worked fine to drive beamers... worked on two macs fine

Comment: But this is mac mini, it is 2012, I forgot to comment and I saw many people that even with mac mini from 2014 it did not work either

Comment: (IMO) HDMI is a horrible connection format.  If you're converting from HDMI to anything, always get an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283979/119271)

Answer (score 2):

> I understood is that from HDMI to VGA, it does not send a signal since it is analog and it does not work.

No.  HDMI sends a signal, but as you've already noted, one is digital and the other is analog.  The signal is there, but it may not be sufficient enough to be detected.

> My question is could I go from HDMI to DVI, then from DVI to VGA; would it work?

No, I don't advise this at all (note:  it may "work," but it won't be reliable). A general rule is *more conversions = more points of failure*.   You are better off making a single conversion:  HDMI → VGA.  Less complexity = better reliability.

**Your best bet is to get an active [HDMI to VGA adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283977/119271).**

The key to getting a reliable signal is using an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271). (The above link described a similar question regarding a Mac mini as well).   The difference between an active and a passive adapter is that the former recreates the actual signal whereas the latter only "reorganizes" the pins outs.