# 4k Monitor, 2014 Macbook air, and an all around DILEMMA

Tags: mac, display, 4k

I would like to get a 27 inch 4k display to hook up to my early 2014 macbook air. My Early 2014 Macbook air only has a thunderbolt 1 connection and I an aware it is not possible to get 4k quality through my thunderbolt 1 connector.

Could I still use the display, using a thunderbolt 1 to thunderbolt 3 adaptor, and get a decent quality, perhaps 2k, on it without anything looking distorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbolt 1 is not "forward compatible" with Thunderbolt 3;  Thunderbolt 3 is ***backward*** compatible with Thunderbolt 1.  So, you cannot go TB1 >> TB3

That said, TB (1, 2, or 3) is a "multiplexing" of different signals - PCIe, DisplayPort, power, and USB(TB3).  What you need to do is connect the "video" signal from the Thunderbolt Port to your monitor.

So, what you need is a [mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/mini-display-port-to-display-port) to connect to your 27" monitor.  Your monitor should be able to adjust to the lower resolution while maintaining quality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that makes a lot more sense. So the monitor I get will have to have a DisplayPort cable input because if the monitor only had a USB-C input it wouldn't be compatible?

Comment: Chances are it will have it.  You can go DP to HDMI, but I am not a fan of converting signals.  If you must go DP to HDMI, get an *active* adapter.  See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275532/macbook-air-occasionally-freezes-when-external-monitor-is-connected/275978#275978) for more details.