# Cannot get 4k monitor to work with macbook air early 2014?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, 4k

I have an early 2014 macbook air and per [this](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT206587) I can connect it with a 4K monitor with *some* success.

After resetting the NVRAM (Opt+Cmd+P+R) I got my Display Settings to show ASUS VP28U with **mirror** option ticked.

However, the monitor does not show anything. Given the fact it detected the display **and** made my macbook screen **super small** , is there a workaround ?

As soon as mirror option is unticked, my screen reverts to old display.

FYI, I have found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285435/4k-monitor-2014-macbook-air-and-an-all-around-dilemma) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275532/macbook-air-occasionally-freezes-when-external-monitor-is-connected/275978#275978) post but they do not work ?