# Connecting a 2015 MacBook Air to a Dell monitor with DP and HDMI ports

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have a [MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp714?locale=en_US) which I want to connect to a [Dell 24 USB-C Hub Monitor - P2422HE](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-24-usb-c-hub-monitor-p2422he/apd/210-bbch/monitors-monitor-accessories). Which cable is best suited for this connection? The monitor has DisplayPort and HDMI ports. Additionally, I was also confused between Thunderbolt 2 (which my MacBook has) and Mini DisplayPort: I wouldn't want to buy a cable with Mini DisplayPort (instead of Thunderbolt 2) and have it not be compatible.

Comment: Get a quality [DisplayPort Cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285437/119271) as it’s the native signal.  If you go with HDMI, you’ll be converting from DisplayPort to HDMI.  Thunderbolt 1/2 Uses the same connector as mDP.  The DP signal is a subset of Thunderbolt. So, if you have a TB port and cable, you get DP automatically.  If you have a mDP port, all you’ll get is DP.

Comment: @Allan Thanks a lot. If you put this as an answer, I will upvote it. Also, does having a gold-plated cable matter?

Comment: Both linked answers touch on my comment, i was just summarizing for you. As for gold plating, in the old analog days, yes.  For digital, buying cables with gold plated connectors is just a way to extract money from your wallet.

Comment: For anyone else wondering in the future, an mDP to DP port works. Just confirmed.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  DP is such a strong technology that doesn’t get enough attention.