# Macbook and 4K monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, 4k

Please, does anyone know whether Macbook (2015) with MacOS Sierra (10.12) is able to drive Dell P2415Q 4K (3840x2160) monitor at 60Hz? What dongles do I need?

I have [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) which is said to support "UHD (3840 by 2160) at 30Hz". But Apple's [Using 4K displays, 5K displays, and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587) states:

> With macOS 10.12 or later, MacBook (2015 and later) and MacBook Pro (2016 and later) support these resolutions and refresh rates over HDMI 1.4b using the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter:
>
> - 4096x2304 at 48Hz refresh rate
> - 3840x2160 at 60Hz refresh rate (mirroring is not supported at this resolution)
>
> MacBook (2016 and later) and MacBook Pro (2016 and later) support 60Hz refresh rates over HDMI when used with a supported HDMI 2.0 display, an HDMI Premium Certified cable, and a supported USB-C to HDMI 2.0 adapter.

So I'm confused now: would it work somehow? Would it work over HDMI? Would it work over DisplayPort? Is the adapter I have suitable?

Comment: Wouldn't something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-Thunderbolt-Compatible/dp/B01J6DT070) work?

Comment: @NoahL That would be an option, perhaps, but unfortunately the Macbook only has one USB C port so I'm not sure how would I charge it, hence that Multiport Adapter..?

Comment: Have you contacted Dell and asked them?  There's several dozen "will this adapter work with my Mac?" questions on the site, have you searched for similar questions/answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is yes with the right USB C to DP adapter. I have a 2015 MacBook and I have tried it with two very different 4K displays - one Philips, one LG - and both worked correctly at 4K 60Hz. If fact, they work in Bootcamp, too at 4K 60hz. Impressive.

FYI, I understand this capability arrived with the Sierra MacOS update. Earlier MacOS versions limit you to 30Hz on this MacBook.

I use a Club3D branded adapter.

Comment: How do you charge the Macbook if the USB-C port is used for DP adapter? Do the monitors supply the power or does the adapter have additional USB-C ports?

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple's [MacBook Specifications page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP712?locale=en_US):

> #### Intel HD Graphics 5300
>
> Dual display and video mirroring:
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
> and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on an external display, both at millions
> of colors

What's important to understand here is that this is not a Thunderbolt port - this is USB-C only.

[image]

So, to make this work, you need an [Active USB-C to DisplayPort Adapter](http://radnex.us/Plugable-USB-C-DisplayPort-Active) or an [Active USB-C to HDMI Adapter](http://radnex.us/Trend-Net-USB-C-HDMI-Adapter)

Please reference this post where I detail the difference between [Active vs. Passive Adapters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275532/macbook-air-occasionally-freezes-when-external-monitor-is-connected/275978#275978)

Comment: Allan, OP is specifying the 2015 MacBook, not the 2015 MacBook Pro, and specifies the USB-C adapter they have, so I am pretty sure OP is NOT referring to the same laptop you are.

Comment: @NoahL - you're right...I don't know why I saw "pro" in his question.

Comment: Thanks, but the cited page is for the current line of Macbooks, whereas 2015 model has Intel HD 5300.

Comment: @Rhem - true...I fixed it, though the solution is still exactly the same.