# Acer XB280HK monitor cannot connect to new MacBook Pro 2018 Thunderbolt 3 port

Tags: macbook-pro

My Acer XB280HK monitor works fine with my old MacBook Pro and Thunderbolt 2 port but neither the HDMI to Thunderbolt 3 cable nor the adapter Thunderbolt 2 to 3 get the Display to work. Can somebody recommend a cable or adapter that works?

Comment: See this relevant [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327136/119271).  Though it's about a Dell monitor, it's basically the exact same config - Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort - and thus the answer is the same.

Comment: Thank you Allan, but there were issues with HDMI-Thunderbolt 2 cables that did not work as well, although I finally got the correct one to connect the Acer.

I had purchased the Moshi HDMI-Thunderbolt 3 cable at Apple store, but it worked only one time and never again. As I experienced cable/handshake issues with the Thunderbolt 2 connection  there are also some with the Thunderbolt 3 cables. Can anybody recommend a working HDMI-TB3 cable that works with a variety of displays?

Comment: DisplayPort (part of Thunderbolt) to DisplayPort will be the most reliable.  If must go with HDMI, get an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286715/119271) as the signals are completely different..