# MacBook Pro 2011 miniDisplay port VS Hdmi - Best Adapter?

Tags: mac, display, hdmi, displayport, macports

I've got a 2011 MacbookPro 2011 with miniDisplay port, and a I Recently bought this beautiful monitor: [Asus VS248HR Gaming Monitor](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B014RKZ81O/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I currently have a VGA adaptor, and even though that is a really nice monitor, it doesn't seem like one over the VGA connection type; therefore I would like to buy a HDMI adaptor and connect my new monitor over HDMI.

I've found several cheap adaptors on amazon, but a couple of questions bug my head:

- **One**: can I possibly have a good resolution/overall good vision performance if I use one of those cheap HDMI adaptors you can find on Amazon, or I need to buy the more expensive Apple one?
- **Second** question: will my resolution improve after connecting the new monitor over HDMI?

Thank you guys

Comment: Related:  [What should I consider before buying external monitor for my MBP?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295270/119271).  "Cheap" is not the issue per se.  It's whether or not it's *active* or *passive*.  Active will always be better and cost more.  But it's much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Your MacBook Pro is officially capable of displaying an external resolution of 2560 x 1600 pixels. Using a HDMI cable is not going to improve on this.

As far as the type of MiniDisplay port > HDMI adapter you opt for, we can't comment on *one of those cheap HDMI adaptors you can find on Amazon* as there are countless cheap adapters around and you'd really have to specify a specific model. However, what I can tell you is:

- You don't need to buy the more expensive Apple one.
- You should opt for a reputable well known brand if you're not going to buy an Apple one, not just a cheap and nasty brand you've never heard of before, as the quality of cable/connector can make a real difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to predict the improvement you may get from switching to an all-digital signal from your Mac to your monitor. It is *reasonable* to assume that there will be an improvement but depending on your eyesight and the monitor's electronics you may or may not see an improvement.

And, generally speaking, as long as a cable or adaptor meets the specifications called for a brand name cable/adaptor is generally no different than a generic brand adaptor.

Note that sometimes a generic product will not be as well constructed as the Apple one. meaning it **might** fail sooner than the Apple one. But certainly not always.

Rule of thumb I go by is how much are you saving? If the generic product is half (or less) of the cost of the brand name one it might be worth it (assuming the quality isn't shite) if it's only a couple of bucks spring for the brand name.