# Connect 2017 iMac to an HDMI tv?

Tags: imac, hdmi

What cable do I need for that? I've seen different things in different places, never specifically for the 2017 iMac with the following specs:

- 2017 27" iMac Retina 5K
- 24GB RAM
- Radeon Pro 580 8GB
- macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 2):

You need a Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI converter.  Your iMac has two Thunderbolt 3 (with the USB-C form factor).  This converter is available from Apple.  Make sure to buy the Thunderbolt3 to HDMI converter, and not Thunderbolt-2 to HDMI, as Thunderbolt3 uses USB-C, and Thunderbolt2 uses miniDisplayPort

My source for the information about your iMac: [EveryMac.com - Apple iMac 27-Inch "Core i5" 3.8 (5K, Mid-2017) Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.8-27-inch-aluminum-retina-5k-mid-2017-specs.html#macspecs2)

You should be able to get 4k output if your television is capable of that resolution (3840x2160).  In other words, you will get no higher than your television's resolution.

Comment: Good answer, +1.  However,  I wouldn't recommend the Apple adapter because it's *passive.*. For best results when going from DisplayPort (the video out of a Thunderbolt port) to HDMI is to use an [active HDMI adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384715/119271) because those signals are very different and you will likely encounter issues going between the two.