# Dell E2720HS flickering as external MacBook Pro monitor

Tags: display, mojave, hdmi

I have an MBP 2012 model. I have Dell E2620HS and connecting it with an HDMI adapter via the Thunderbolt port. It has been flickering as it comes on and off.

I tried reconnecting cable but it didn't help. My OS is mojave 10.14.6
Edit: here is a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12k-WFatbYcUdu_VdwkCV0kpNh2dqZm_c/view?usp=sharing) of flickering

Comment: Is this question about the flickering and how to solve or is this a purchasing question?  If the former, we're going to need more info like the OS you're running, the adapter you're using, etc.  If the latter, you need to look over at [Hardware Recomendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as shopping questions are off topic here.

Comment: @Allan it’s about flickering. My macOS is Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: I went ahead and removed your purchasing question then, but we still need some additional details.  Do you have access to another monitor you can use to test out?  This will help rule out whether it's your Mac or the monitor.  It's also helpful if you describe or even video the flickering so we can get a better "look."

Comment: @Allan I don't have another monitor. I have added the video clip as well, it is showing the adapter as well.

Comment: Your video is in accessible.  But if it's about flickering, it's been addressed before - more than likely you need an [active HDMI adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271).  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384715/119271) regarding flickering.

Comment: This issue could be related to the HDMI adapter. Do use the Original Apple adapter or a Third-Party hardware?

Comment: @howdytom third party, also today I saw green jumbled up the screen while it flicked.

Comment: If you're seeing colors (green), it's quite possible you have a GPU issue.  Try [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting) to see if it finds any issue, however, you need to somehow connect your Mac to a different monitor - if you can't do any sort of diagnostics, you're limited to just wild guesses.

Comment: @Allan today My MacBook pro when I opened it has a lot of glitches and a green screen all over the place. But I ran what you mentioned above. it says everything is fine but if that is a GPU issue, why didn't it prompted so?

Comment: The diagnostic tools are a bit like the check engine light in your car (mechanics call it an "idiot light.").  If it comes on, there's *definitely* something wrong, but there could be an issue and it never light up.  Same with Apple Diag; the fact you got no error codes doesn't indicate nothing's wrong.  However, if you got a diagnostic code, you'd know for sure something was amiss (I was hoping for the latter).  You really need to try this on a different monitor to see if it continues and to narrow the problem to either your Mac or the display.

Comment: Just letting you know (again) that the video you provided is not accessible.  The bounty won't do yo much good to attract answers if nobody can get to the info to make a sound diagnosis!

Comment: @Allan try now. I called Apple genius but the cs rep. Said he have no idea about such thing . Which is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the adapter I was using was dodgy, now I removed it and got myself thunderbolt to HDMI cable, it is clear and no flickering.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the HDMI adapter is compatible with MacBook. Some HDMI adapter isn't and makes your screen flicker.

Comment: This is not correct - there's no such thing as an HDMI adapter not compatible with Mac.  The adapter takes a signal (DisplayPort most likely) and converts it to another signal (HDMI); the OS plays no part in this.  However, converting from DP to HDMI can cause issues because the signals are very different.  This is why I recommend [active adapters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271) if you must convert, but it's preferable you don't and use a monitor with DisplayPort input(s).