# Possible to get 1440p from a 2012 Mac Mini via mini DP -> HDMI adapter?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport, resolution

I recently purchased a 2012 Mac Mini and am attempting to max out my dual monitor setup.

Currently, I connect my Mac to a [Dell S2417DG](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/339637.pdf)'s HDMI 1.4 in via [this passive mini DP to HDMI 1.4 cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0194Y3XFQ). According to the specifications, 1440p should be possible, yet macOS only offers a 1080p maximum in System Preferences > Displays.

After some exploration, I found and applied [this patch](https://github.com/Floris497/mac-pixel-clock-patch-V2), which made a 2560 x 1440 resolution available in Displays. Enabling this resolution, however, doesn't work, and the monitor indicates that there is no longer an input signal. I have also tried setting up 1440p via SwitchResX and verified that all timings are correct according to the monitor manual, but when I apply the custom resolution, the display stays in 1080p mode.

**Is it possible to achieve 1440p via mDP -> HDMI on a 2012 Mac Mini?**

I am running High Sierra (10.13.3).

I am aware that a working solution would be to use mDP -> DisplayPort, but my gaming PC takes up the DP slot for 1440p@165hz.

Comment: You need an *active adapter*.  See this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271

Comment: @Allan I read [here](https://www.startech.com/faq/displayport_converter_dp_multi_mode) that Thunderbolt does the necessary conversion so I purchased passive originally. My display connection *quality* is perfect, just limited to 1080p. Is my understanding here correct? Either way, I ordered the active cable yesterday so I'll try it out in a few days, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected and as Allan suggested in the comments, I needed an active adapter. [This cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FM50QJC), which is the active version of the passive cable I originally purchased, did the trick; I now have 1440p via mDP -> HDMI.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a special set up. Make sure your monitor is 1440p and with display port input, it will work automatic. I have a Benq GW2765 1440p connect to my 2012 Mac mini through display port. It work perfectly. mDP to HDMI will not work. I have tried one that claim can support 4K which still stay in 1080p only.

Answer (score 0):

I just got my Mini Display Port to Display Port cable and my LG monitor is displaying 1440p at 60hz from my Late 2012 Mac Mini. None other combination worked.

I just use the mac for browsing, email and to watch Netflix (now 4K).

It took a while to find this thread and finally make it work. Thanks!