# External Monitor not detected on Macbook Air early 2015, with thunderbolt 2 + HDMI

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have always been wanting to connect my macbook air to an external monitor, so after researching the best types for macbooks, I figured connecting my macbook via HDMI to a monitor would work.

However, I have connected everything up with no success. I made sure to first shut down and restart my laptop, and when fully booted connect the mini display adapter into my mac, and connect one of the HDMI cables to the adapter. I then connected the end of the HDMI cable to my monitor's HDMI dock. After switching on my monitor and waiting for it to connect, I realised that my macbook was not registering the device. Yes, my mouse was lagging a bit while my monitor was attempting to connect, so I think it knows it's there, but I could not connect it.

I have tried various solutions:

Uninstall Display Drivers -> restart -> install new display drivers again -> restart -> connect Monitor + Macbook again
Clear recent items -> unplug all devices -> shut down -> reboot with command + option + s + power button -> connect everything again once logged
I tried to reset the System Management Controller on my macbook by shutting down and Shift-Control-Option and the power button, and then turning it back on.

If it helps, this is the display I'm connecting to: KA251Q | Monitors - Tech Specs & Reviews - Acer

None of these work. I am losing patience and hope. Could someone please help me fix this nasty problem? <3

Comment: Is the input for the monitor selected to HDMI? How can you tell your Mac isn't registering the device? Have you looked in the Display settings and seen if the monitor shows up?

Comment: Well my monitor has 3 options: VGA, HDMI and Digital Cable. I have always pressed on the HDMI option on the monitor screen. I have also held down 'option' in my mac's display settings and it's not detecting the screen.

Comment: I would try it with another cable. Maybe the one you have has gone bad.

Comment: Thank you :) actually going today to see if other HDMI cables/adapters work. will update here.

Comment: Personally, I would stay away from HDMI, but if you want to use HDMI, you should be using an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275532/macbook-air-occasionally-freezes-when-external-monitor-is-connected/275978#275978).  With your setup, you are going from mini DisplayPort to HDMI and those signals are quite different.

Comment: So should I opt to use a VGA cable?

Comment: Hold up, reading the page which you sent :) it's a bit confusing

Comment: Would this be a passive or active adapter? Since I was going to get one from the Apple store but now a bit wary since what you said. https://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/HHLN2ZM/B/belkin-4k-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-adapter?fnode=8b&fs=fh%3D4595%252B3073

Comment: If you are using 1080p or lower resolution, any adapter should work. Have you tried plugging it in to any TVs to see if you get a signal anywhere else? It sounds like it's a monitor issue. The only miniDP to HDMI adapters I've ever seen go bad, went bad after lots of use.

Comment: I ended up buying a better adapter and that worked.