# Connect 2 external monitors (1 VGA + 1 HDMI) to MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, high-sierra, hdmi, vga

I have a 13" 2017 MacBookPro.

I wish to connect two monitors to it, a Samsung HDMI monitor and a LG VGA Monitor. I am using an [Aukey Multiport USB-C Adapter](https://rebrand.ly/aukey).

I can't connect the two monitors at the same time. When I do it, only the HDMI works. If I plug it out from the multiport, the VGA monitor shows up.

What could be the reason for this behaviour? How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that adapter, you can only use 1 video output at a time.  From the product description in the link you provided:

> Alternative Video Outputs: Connect a display to your computer using
>   **either** the HDMI port (4K@30Hz Max resolution) or VGA port (1080p Max
>   resolution). **If both are connected, only HDMI will output**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

To connect two monitors, you need *two* video adapters - an HDMI **and** a separate VGA adapter. The following should work:

- [Type C USB-C HDMI Active Adapter](http://www.radnex.us/Plugable-USB-C-DisplayPort-Active)
- [USB-C Thunderbolt to VGA adapter](http://radnex.us/usbc-mdp-dvi-vga-hdmi-adapter)

I always recommend using [Active Adapters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) because they regenerate the signal from DiaplayPort to actual HDMI or VGA signals.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use the HDMI and VGA port simultaneously with Aukey multiport adapter.

You'll have to look for an alternative. It is advisable to go with 1st party cables and adaptors for the best results.

You can use an [Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter). It is available on Apple Retail Stores and Apple Online Store for $69.00.

Product description from the Apple Online Store web page:

> The USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter lets you connect your USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) enabled Mac to an HDMI display, while also connecting a standard USB device and a USB-C charging cable.

You will additionally need a [Belkin USB-C to VGA Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJUZ2ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-vga-adapter) for connecting the VGA monitor.