# 2 VGA Monitors to Thunderbolt/USB-C on MBP

Tags: display, thunderbolt, vga-adapter

I had a previous monitor setup with two VGA monitors connected to my previous MBP, through mini port or display ports (I cant recall exactly but I had two nice big external monitors).  Long story short my old MBP died and I got a replacement MBK 2018 that has 2 of those Thunderbolt or USB-C connections but no mini display ports/usb/hdmi etc (i'm confused already)....

So.. How do I connect both these VGA monitors to my MBP so they both work?  Neither have HDMI outputs.  The guy in the apple store told me about daisy chaining and wanted to sell me 'two' adapters at £75 quid each...

Anyone any recommendations on how this is done?  Surely this cant be difficult but I cant seem to find any double VGA to Thunderbolt adapters... I'm not even sure if this is what I should be looking for.

Any advice is welcomed, or a pointer to any adapters/hubs/connectors or whatever its called that can connect 2 VGA monitors to my MBP..

(BTW as you can probably tell, my expertise in all things connectory/hubby or adaptery is limited so keep the techy terms simple)

Comment: 75 quid???  He's bonkers!.  A decent VGA adapter is less than $20 USD (about 15 quid). See [this similar answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321594/connect-2-external-monitors-1-vga-1-hdmi-to-macbook-pro/321597#321597) for what to use the for the UBC-C to VGA adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C plug) adapters for VGA. These can be found from lots of different makers at varying prices - i.e. from "unknown China" to "Belkin" to "Apple" in terms of price ranges.

It would ofcourse be ideal if you could have an adapter that in itself offers dual-VGA - then you would only need to plug-in one cable instead of two. I have only seen very few of these, such as for example the HUB-V03 from Choetech. The problem with all of those I have seen is that they only support mirroring. I.e. both monitors will display the same image, which I believe is not what you want.

In general, you might want to consider buying new monitors instead of adapters. It will be more costly, but you'll often get much better quality displays as VGA-only monitors are generally old. One thing is the factory specs (i.e. newer monitors usually have one or more of higher resolution, wider color range, higher light intensity and/or lower power usage) - but take into account that modern monitors actually degrade over time. If your current monitor is 8 years old for example, chance is that it will break at some time - but it is an almost certainty that it currently has worse picture quality than when you bought it.