# Dell Monitor with Apple PC

Tags: display, hardware

I have a 2015 Mac Book Pro. I tried connecting it to an external Dell Model No. E176FPf using a VGA adapter, but nothing happens.  I'm guessing this monitor is just too old to be compatible with newer computers but I just wanted to confirm.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It should work.  I've connected "younger" than yours MacBooks to VGA projectors - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/321597/119271

Comment: That said... you don't say how you're connecting, what specific adapter or cable you're using, what issue specifically you're having or what version of macOS.  This site will work best for you if you provide us with specifics so we can better "see" the issue you're having.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which is the manufacturer and model of the VGA adapter?

Comment: I rolled back your edits @jaume because you changed the premise of the question.  We have to be careful when making edits this substantial.  "Nothing happened" is very different from "not recognized;" we don't know if it was recognized or not.  The monitor could very well be recognized but not display anything.  Let's have the OP contribute the details

Comment: I get your point @Allan, but, after my edit, the body of the question still mentioned "nothing happens", so why not simply correct the title (which is in urgend need of focus) instead of rolling back and losing the link to the monitor specifications that I added for further reference?

Comment: If you just want to confirm, the answer is yes.  On the [tech spec page for the 2015 MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715) it lists "Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter"

Comment: @jaume - it's not urgent and the specs of the monitor isn't critical (though, if you want to link that, it's cool).  The question (which isn't a good one really because there's obviously an underlying issue) is if VGA is compatible.  My above comment confirms it's compatible.  We need more info from the OP to refine his question properly and it's better to wait than to assume.

Comment: This monitor, like many from that era, also has a DVI port on it. You might be better off with a DP -> DVI adapter as the signal path is always digital.

Comment: https://www.walmart.com/ip/USB-3-0-VGA-Adapter-Video-Graphic-Card-Multi-Display-External-Cable-Adapter-PC-Laptop-Windows-Desktop-Laptop-PC-Monitor-Projector/295682642

This the vga adaptor.  I didn’t realize there were specific adapters for Mac versus pc.  By ‘nothing happens’ I mean nothing happens after I click ‘detect displays’.

 I’m guessing  I need to buy a different adaptor.

 I apologize for not including these details in the original post.  I’ve used stack exchange for software/programming related questions but this is my first time using it for hardware related issues.