# Can I output 1080p at 240hz from my 2017 MacBook Pro 13inch with Touch Bar

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I just bought an Acer XB252Q gaming monitor that has 1080p 240hz.

I was wondering if I can output 1080p at 240hz with my 2017 MacBook Pro 13" with Touch Bar using a display port cable?

I ask because on HDMI it only outputs 1080p at 60hz.

Comment: And the MacBook in question would be.......   Please [edit your original question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/321733/edit) with details about which MacBook Pro you are using, the version of macOS.

Comment: macos High Sierra and a macbook pro 2017 with touch bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Because your MacBook only has <s>USB-C</s> Thunderbolt, you will need a <s>USB-C</s> Thunderbolt to DisplayPort adapter. [This Apple USB-C to DisplayPort adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HLR62ZM/A/moshi-usb-c-to-displayport-cable) states that it can provide up to 60hz. [This Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587) covers connecting UHD monitors with your Mac and states (paraphrased):

> The MacBook Pro (2016 and later) can support these resolutions and refresh rates over HDMI 1.4b when using the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter with macOS Sierra 10.12 or later:
>   Up to 1080p at 60Hz
>   3840 x 2160 at 30Hz

Allan is correct, you will probably want an active Thunderbolt to Displayport adapter. I forget USB-C and Thunderbolt are not interchangeable terms.

Comment: While your overall answer is correct, your recommendation is flawed.   Thunderbolt has *native* DisplayPort video so you don't go from USB to TB.  You go from DisplayPort to HDMI; and I wouldn't do it with an Apple adapter - I would use an [*active* adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) instead.

Comment: @Allan I forget USB-C and Thunderbolt aren't the same. Updated to include.

Comment: It's confusing.  What's on the MBP is Thunderbolt 3 which uses a *Type C* connector.  Thunderbolt 3 has USB 3.1, DisplayPort, PCIe, andpower all on one cable so you just need to go from DisplayPort to HDMI.  Just remember that USB-C is the connector *type*, not the specification - that would be USB 3.1

Answer (score 2):

### Hardware

MacBook: 2017 15" MacBook Pro (maxed out)
Display: AOC AGON AG251FWG2 (1920x1080@240Hz)

### Using DisplayPort

I used [this generic 4K@60Hz USB-C to DP adapter](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01N5RFAI4/) and it correctly handled 1080p@240Hz resolution on my MacBook.

### Using HDMI

On my MacBook, I only get 1080p@120Hz since I only have [a 4K@30Hz adapter](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01KLNIGGA) (which would translate to 1080p@120Hz, logically).

However, on my Hackintosh (Vega 64), the maximum refresh rate I get is 1080p@144Hz. So there’s probably also a macOS + HDMI limitation.

### FreeSync

Neither on my MacBook Pro, nor on my Hackintosh, FreeSync works in any of these configurations. I think it’s not supported at all by the macOS drivers.