# Reconnect Thunderbolt programically

Tags: thunderbolt

I have a display connected via Thunderbolt port to my MacBook Air. The cable is Thunderbolt to HDMI. Whenever I wake the computer up, it freezes intermittently, until I either reconnect Thunderbolt cable or reboot. Is there a process to kill or a service to restart that does the same thing?

Comment: How are you connecting to the monitor?  That said, see this question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275532/macbook-air-occasionally-freezes-when-external-monitor-is-connected/275978#275978

Comment: Wow, this seems like what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, it does work great until the computer goes to sleep.

Comment: What manufacturer of adaptor/cable are you using? From years of experience, less well-known manufacturers produce substandard adaptors/cables that may work for a while, or not work at all. Apple- and Belkin- branded cables/adaptors seem to be the best in terms of quality and durability. We now use Kramer HDMI cables with Belkin HDMI <> Thunderbolt adaptors. Both are high-quality items that have lasted several years under normal usage. (Disclaimer: no financial ties to Apple or Belkin.)

Comment: I think it's around $10 samzhe aliexpress cable. It certainly works better than $1.5 one.