# Display not working with Mac mini

Tags: display

I recently bought a new [LG Ultrawide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XFXX5JH) display.

I connected it to my Mac mini with a Display Port to HDMI cable.

But nothing is showing up on it. But it is working with HDMI cable over HDMI port.

What is wrong?

Comment: The most likely cause is the adapter you're using is a passive adapter (it just reorganizes the signals from DP to HDMI).  What you need is an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) that actually recreates the signal.  (I explain more in the link).  However, you should be using a DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable and not do any conversions.  HDMI is a flaky (IMO) technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapters won't support HDMI at higher resolutions, it is possible this adapter won't work at the higher resolution of your new monitor.

At work myself and my colleagues have found this is the case with a lot of cheaper adapters I used to buy, such as this one:

https://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Cable-Adapter-Converter~MDP2HDMI

You could try a new adapter, these are the ones we buy at work and they seem to work well:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Griffin-GC17096-Video-Display-Converter/dp/B003CK8TZ8

Comment: @user3439894 my understanding of the new code of conduct was to be nice to other people. The reason for this is the original draft of my response refered to the fact that at work myself and my colleagues look after a number of Mac Mini's which is why there was a mistake. However there is no need for this kind of attitude towards the community.