# macOS — Is there a way to force HDMI-connection "restart"?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hdmi

I'm using a MacBook Pro (late 2016) with an USB-C-to-HDMI **cable** made by AUKEY to connect to a projector (BenQ, Casio, Epson).

There are days, everything works just fine, and there are days (like today) with no connection at all — my MacBook just doesn't recognize the HDMI-connection (it doesn't change its screen resolution), so it doesn't send any signal to the projector.

[image]

So, my question is: Is there a way to force the HDMI-connection "restart"?

I'm running macOS 10.13.6 and yes, I know, I should use an original or certified USB-C-to-HDMI adapter with a HDMI cable, but since the AUKEY cable works *almost* always, is there a possibility for a software solution?

"System Preferences — Displays — Detect Displays" doesn't help.

Comment: That's actually a passive Type C DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.  An [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) will solve the issue.

Comment: Does a restart fix the issue? But what Allan said: go for the active adapter, they are a bit pricier but as you have discovered the cheaper ones are, well, *cheaper*

Comment: @Allan For some reason it does work now (again), so I assume the cable is not broken (?). Could it be something like a grounding (?) issue. I’m switching between a lot of projectors (same model, different rooms) on a same day and my MacBook is running on battery all the time. Thank you for your link.

Comment: It's signaling and voltage.  DisplayPort is 3V and HDMI is 5V.  If that pin isn't high enough (i.e. the tolerance is "too tight") it won't see the signal.  Also, HDMI uses a clock signal where DP doesn't provide it.  You can get things to work by power cycling, but the end result is it's not a "proper" connector to give you a reliable connection.