# External monitor waking up often

Tags: display

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2016 with touchbar running High Sierra. I've got an external display connected over HDMI to a usb-c dongle (Apple's).

When I put the laptop to sleep, the monitor continuously cycles between waking up, displaying "no signal" view, and sleeping for a few seconds.

What's the best way to debug/fix it?

Comment: More than likely, your issue is that you’re using a *passive* adapter and not an *active* one.  See my [post on active vs. passive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978) for more details.

Comment: @Allan I'm using the Digital AV Multiport Adapter from Apple, which I'm pretty sure is an active one.