# External monitor connected to MacBook Pro says, "Entering Power Save Mode"

Tags: macbook-pro, display, vga-adapter

I am running macOS Mojave on a MacBoo kPro. I have connected an external monitor, a Dell E2214H to it using a Cable Matters adapter.

On my MacBook Pro, under System Preferences → Displays, there is no Arrangement tab. I reconnected everything, rebooted in safe mode which didn't change anything.

I know for sure that the monitor works. So, what could be the reason the laptop is not recognizing it?

Comment: Have you tested if the adapter is working on another computer?

Comment: No, that is the only thing I am unable to test at this point as I don't have another machine with a HDMI port.

Comment: Was the same display with the same adapter working previously? Have you tested the same port(s) on your MacBook with other devices. This way you can segregate the culprit.

Comment: Why are you connecting to VGA?  You should at least go from a digital signal (HDMI) to another digital signal (DVI) instead of analog (VGA).  Also, I highly recommend that you get an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) instead of a passive one.