# Mac Mini 2018 - 3 monitors

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt, hdmi

I've seen this question for older versions of the Mac mini, but I'm struggling to find an answer for the Mac mini 2018.

I want to connect 3 identical monitors (22inch 1080p). I'm currently able to connect 2 monitors using HDMI-Thunderbolt 3 cables, but I'm unable to get the 3rd monitor to detect a signal. I have a 3rd HDMI-Thunderbolt 3 cable, and I also have a VGA to HDMI adapter I can use as well.

If I plug the VGA-HDMI cable into he HDMI port on the Mini, the two functioning monitors begin to flicker. The third monitor is still not detecting a signal.

The monitor is a 1920x1080, 75 Hz

Has anyone successfully configured a 2018 Mac Mini to 3 monitors using one of these configurations?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate? The referenced question addresses older Mac Minis. I can confirm that the answer by Allan works for my Mac Mini 2018, i.e. one monitor via HDMI and two monitors via Thunderbolt 3 ports.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t use three Thunderbolt 3 ports to drive three displays.   You can accomplish this by connecting two Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI adapters/cables and one HDMI to HDMI/VGA/DVI adapter via the HDMI port.

A couple of things to consider when connecting monitors:

- Use *native* signals rather than convert.  Thunderbolt 3 is also DisplayPort, so it’s better to go from TB3 to mDP/DP
- If you must convert video signals, use an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) instead as it actually recreate the native video signal

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple](https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/)

> Up to three displays: Two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at
> 60Hz connected via Thunderbolt 3 plus one display with 4096-by-2160
> resolution at 60Hz connected via HDMI 2.0 [...]

So it is important to not exceed the maximum resolution supported.

Your 1080p Monitors seem to meet that spec so you will need to look at your cabling setup. It is good that you got the Thunderbolt to work, can you attach the third monitor via the Mini's HDMI port?

Comment: If I plug the VGA-HDMI cable into he HDMI port on the Mini, the two functioning monitors begin to flicker. The third monitor is still not detecting a signal.  The monitor is a 1920x1080, 75 Hz

Comment: Other than trying different cables, I'm sorry, I am out of ideas...

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/

I think you're getting into trouble by trying to run a monitor at 75 Hz. Either lower the resolution or the refresh rate. Try 800x600@60. Once that's stable, step it up a notch until you know the limits.

I would also be susipscious of the quality of your HDMI to VGA adapter/cable. Does your monitor have an HDMI connector or perhaps DVI or mini-Displayport? VGA should always be the last alternative; things get freaky when you introduce analog to the mix.