# 4K monitor not showing in 4K on my Macbook Pro (late 2011)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I just bought a new monitor (the LG 27UL500) which should support 4K to connect with my Macbook Pro. I've connected my Macbook Pro with an Mini DisplayPort to HDMI connector (which should support 4K) to my monitor.

But now my Macbook only gives me the option to set it to 1080p. I've tried to 'hack' my monitor with SwitchResX to 2560x1600 but the quality seems to stay the same.

Is it my Macbook Pro video card that can't handle the 4K? Because on [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-13-late-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html) it says that my Macbook should be able to handle a second screen of 2560x1600. It’s not 4K but still better then the 1080p I have right now.

Having a 4K monitor which only displays 1080p is kinda useless. Can someone help me get this monitor to display the max possible resolution?

Specs of my Macbook Pro:
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)
Processor: 2,8 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory: 16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 (was originally only 4GB)
Videocard: Intel HD-video 3000 512 MB

Comment: Are you using an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) versus a passive cable?

Comment: Voted to reopen, but still my question is valid - what type of adapter are you using?