# Thunderbolt 3 dock won't output to external display

Tags: display, video, thunderbolt

I have a 15" MBP 2019 model.  I also have a StarTech Thunderbolt 3 dock with 2 Displayport outputs.  I went out today and bought a cheap Philips 27" display (M7273VQ1L) to use when working from home.  Supports DVI, HDMI and VGA inputs.  I have it connected with a StarTech DisplayPort<->DVI cable.   OSX doesn't detect any display being connected via this configuration.  The monitor supports VGA,DVI & HDMI.  I figured that since DisplayPort is supposed to be legacy compatible with DVI it would be able to auto-configure the resolution via this adapter cable.  Am I missing something?
Would a better solution to use a DisplayPort->HDMI adapter and use that port on the monitor?

Comment: There's a few too many unknowns to make a definitive assessment - is the dock fully functional as is the the monitor?  What dock is it?  Start off by confirming that the display works by plugging it directly into your Mac.  Go from DisplayPort Type C (USB-C) to DVI or HDMI (make sure you're using an [Active Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271))  Once we know that the monitor works, we can turn out attention to the Dock.

Comment: As an aside...you will likely get a more reliable (and easier to setup) connection if you get a monitor with native DisplayPort.  Your Mac natively outputs DP so there's no conversion to DVI, VGA, or HDMI.

Comment: Yes the dock has heretofore worked fine with 2 monitors using a DisplayPort connection.  I decided to not take this further, returned the monitor and got a Lenovo 27" IPS display with native USB-C connection so I can just bypass the dock entirely.