# BigSur Blurry Text on external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, big-sur

I have looked all over the internet and I have seen this issue popup all the time, but none of the 'fixes' seem to work for me.

I have recently switched from a pc to a mac.
I run 3x monitors off my computer and on PC I have had no issues what so ever.

I have a 2019 MacBookPro which is now running Big Sur. (I have recently formatted the computer also to start fresh after my switch from the PC about a month ago).

My initial 1080p monitors (hdmi to displayport) work perfectly fine on the pc, but on the mac I am having issues.

I use a [Kensington SD4900P](https://www.kensington.com/p/products/featured-products/sd4900p-usb-c-and-usb-3.0-10gbps-triple-4k-hybrid-dock-60w-pd-dp-hdmi-winmacchrome/) hub to connect all my bits and pieces to the mac.  Everything works fine other than the displays.

I thought they might be the monitors so I upgraded all three to the [LG UltraGear 27GL850-B 27"](https://www.lg.com/nz/it-monitors/lg-27GL850-B) thinking that Mac work with LG to create a 5k monitor that LG would be the way to go, but still nothing is working for me.

I have purchased a [USB-C to DisplayPort cable](https://www.unitek-products.com/products/usb-3-1-type-c-to-displayport-cable) to see if this helps, but nope, nothing there either.  The only difference with the cable running directly into the mac is I get a 'High Dynamic Range' option, which when ticked seems to work a bit, however, it does make my monitor really dull, which is a bit frustrating.

I have also tried resetting my SMC and also the following commands (all with a restart between them)

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool FALSE
defaults write com.apple.Safari CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool FALSE
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 3
defaults -currentHost write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 0
defaults -currentHost write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

Nothing seems to be helping.  I have already spent upwards of $3k (nzd) on trying to get this to work I really don't want to have to go and switch back to my pc for work.

Are there any other suggestions that I can try to get this to work?  It is also starting to give me a bit of a headache / sore eyes, which is not good as I stare at my screens all day.

I should also mention that my mac display is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

So for my issue so far I have changed the view mode on the monitors from 'Vivid' to 'sRGB' and it seems to have sorted out the monitors a fair bit.

I will still try another cable, but for now, things are looking a lot better

Answer (score 0):

Check the maximum resolution that is supported by the monitor cable. I had a similar problem as I was using an HDMI to miniDP cable which maxed out at 1080p.

Changing to a Display Port cable immediately resolved this issue.

In my understanding, you need a Display Port cable (version 1.2 or above) that supports higher resolutions (2k or 4k). Check out the image below for supported resolutions for different display port standards. Source [link](https://www.cablematters.com/blog/DisplayPort/displayport-1-4-vs-1-2).

[image]