# Adding third monitor for Mac Pro (late 2013)

Tags: display, thunderbolt, mac-pro

I have a late 2013 Mac Pro (the desktop tower! not a MacBook) running on Monterey.
I can successfully connect two monitors but if I add a third monitor then one of the first two disappears.
I am connecting them all with the [Thunderbolt cables](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B0134V29UA?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title) and have tried various tricks so far:

- Switching around the ports where the cables are plugged in
- Switching one of the thunderbolt cables to HDMI
- Restarting, unplugging, reconnecting
- **Detect displays** under Display preferences

Please any help would be gratefully appreciated.
The monitors are all [Lenovo L24e-30](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/monitors/home/66bckcc2us); I’m starting to wonder if these are just not compatible with Mac.

Tried the same setup with a previous Mac Mini and also couldn’t get that to work.

Comment: What resolution are the displays?

Comment: All 1080p, exact monitor is Lenovo L24e-30

Comment: Hmm… OK, then it ought to 'just work'. You only need the 2xTB 1xHDMI trick for 5k displays.

Comment: Could it be the cables I am using? Have the Amazon Basics ones

Comment: 1080p screens should work with anything, they're not 'high tech'. I wouldn't really like to guess, tbh, I don't want to have you spend money that might not fix it.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B0134V29UA?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title

Comment: Have linked the exact cables I got - still within the returns period so I could try a different brand etc if this could be the issue

Comment: Ah, they're DP to HDMI not thunderbolt cables. That might change the game but I'm not good enough on video specs [& that particular Mac Pro GPU] to be certain.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/QGECEN-Thunderbolt-Displayport-Microsoft-Supports-Black/dp/B08HYM3155/ref=mp_s_a_1_5?crid=2GIG73PW3IWMC&keywords=thunderbolt+to+hdmi&qid=1671641687&sprefix=thunderbolt+to+%2Caps%2C147&sr=8-5

Comment: Is this a thunderbolt cable? Not sure what I should be looking for other than just the description calling it TB. Thanks so much for all your help btw

Comment: Neither Apple spec - https://support.apple.com/kb/SP697?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US - nor Everymac - https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-eight-core-3.0-xeon-e5-gray-black-cylinder-late-2013-specs.html - gives *actual* cable requirements & I don't have enough experience with TB->[any]. All my old Macs are still on DVI or DP-DP, no adaptors.

Comment: Ahhh…converting from mDP to HDMI.  The cables you linked are **not** TB; they are DisplayPort to HDMI and unfortunately, they are passive.  You need an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271).  TB cables are at least 3x the price.  Also, the proper DP to HDMI adapter will be about 2x the price of those cables.

Comment: Just to update - I ordered new active connector cables and now works perfectly as expected. Big thank you to Tetsujin and @Allan for solving this

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: \o/ Glad it got you fixed [sorry, been away for xmas]