# Connecting Macbook Air (early 2015) to HDMI projector for Keynote

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, keynote

I'm trying to connect my Macbook Air (early 2015) to a projector via an HDMI cable (for a Keynote presentation).

I seem to only have a thunderbolt 2 port.

Is it possible to get an adapter to connect through Thunderbolt  to HDMI?

Comment: You need an [Active mDP to HDMI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244885/119271) adapter.  This is no different than connecting a monitor or TV